# Writing Arabic text in longlistselector in xaml

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, textbox, arabic

I am making a windows 8 phone app and I want to add arabic text items to a longlistselector. Its orientation is supposed to be right from left but I cannot get it to align in the proper direction. Is there a way in Windows 8 xaml to detect the reading order of the text and adjust alignment accordingly?

Comment: I do not think you want to set the alignment, but the FlowDirection to "RightToLeft". If you know the language ahead of time then you could bind your FlowDirection to an IValueConverter so that it sets the direction based on the language or you can use a language detection service. Check out: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj712703.aspx for more information on bidirectional strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the Window/Page level, add the following property

```
FlowDirection="RightToLeft"
```

This is a Bindable property, so it can be set at Application Level, and the changes reflected with minimal amount of code.